# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '234 hyd' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I used the below query to convert and replace at the same time.

```
SELECT Isnull(MAX(CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(REPLACE(mycolum,'234 hyd'+' ', ''), 'c', ''))), 0) + 1
FROM   mytable
```

Ans like :---234 hyd c1, 234 hyd c2, 234 hyd c3 ......

Comment: Which DBMS are you using. That is non-standard SQL

Comment: using sql management studio 2008

Comment: SSMS isn't a database. SQL Server is. And `10270 G4` is *not* an integer. Check and clean up your data. It's *your* statement that manipulates the strings, comes up with the text and then tries to turn it into an integer

Comment: yes,10270 g4 is not integer but it is stored in another table column.i have to read that value and replace with +1 means output should be 10270 g5.

Comment: some sample data would be nice, what is in centername ? what is in villagename ? what is in prefix ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query below. It selects the number from the centername and after that it adds the villigename and the prefix.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @maxcount IS NULL 
       THEN CONCAT(MAX(CAST(CenternameA AS INT)) +1, @villagename, ' ', @prefix)
FROM(   
    SELECT (SUBSTRING(centername, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', centername), 8000),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(centername, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', centername), 8000) AS CenternameA
           FROM centermastertable
    WHERE villageid = @villageid
    )
```

Please note it only works in sql server 2012 or higher.
The code to select the number can be found [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/)

Comment: My total query. Like.                                           SELECT Isnull(MAX(CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(REPLACE(mycolum, '345 hyd'+' ', ''),'c', ''))), 0) + 1
FROM   mytable